# Visual Studio Deployment Package Change File Permissions

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

Maybe this isn't possible due to Security implications...
I have a Deployment Package created in Visual Studio for a Win Form. The application references an app.config file locally and allows the user to change the settings in it, through the application. 
When I deploy the application and attempt to save the changes I have made, Windows is saying "Permission denied". Is there a command I can run as part of the installation that will give the "Everyone" security permission to my app.config file....and thus allow my Application to edit it?

Thank you.

Comment: where is your app.config file located, in the same directory as the executable?

Comment: Yes it is in the same folder as the executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to write to the app.config file you need to move it to the Shared Application Data directory and modify your application to read the configuration information from there. On Win7 for example:

> C:\ProgramData\YourCompany\YourApp\app.config

In C#, to get the common app data directory:

```
// using System.IO;
string appDataDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```

Comment: Thank you .This did the job nicely :)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use a custom action in your installer to run [icacls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28v=ws.10%29) in order give full access to Everyone:

`icacls {Path to App.config} /grant Everyone:(F)`

Comment: So I would have to add a class, add this code to it and then add that output as a custom action in the installer?
Is there a way of just running the command without coding the class, as part of the installation?

Comment: Right, you can look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/827018) if you need an example. Your class would have one line of code, but I don't know if adding a setup assembly to your solution is going to be a big deal or not. I'm pretty sure you can run icacls directly from a custom action, but only from a more advanced installer solution like InstallShield.